# BlackBerry OS 5 - 7 - Trying to get JSON response and get error code 500

Tags: android, json, mobile, blackberry

I have been trying to get the json response from  my company's json webservice. Here is the code:

```
public final static String GOINOUT_HOST_NAME = "http://ec2-54-254-123-244.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com";
public final static String GOINOUT_API_VERSION = "/api/v1";

public final static String GOINOUT_FACEBOOK_AUTHENTICATE = GOINOUT_HOST_NAME + GOINOUT_API_VERSION + "/facebook_authenticate";

public static JSONObject loginGoinoutWithFacebook(String accessToken) {
    JSONObject goinoutUserJsonObject = null;
    try {
        Hashtable params = new Hashtable();
        params.put("access_token", accessToken);
        String paramsString = StringUtil.toURLParameters(params);

        Hashtable properties = new Hashtable();
        String response = HttpUtils.sendGoinoutJsonRequest(GOINOUT_FACEBOOK_AUTHENTICATE + "?" + paramsString, paramsString, HttpUtils.TIMEOUT, properties, HttpConnection.POST);
        Dialog.alert("res: " + response);
        JSONObject goinoutJsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
        goinoutUserJsonObject = new JSONObject(goinoutJsonObject.getString("user"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Dialog.alert("e1: " + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e1) {
        Dialog.alert("e2: " + e1.getMessage());
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    return goinoutUserJsonObject;
}
```

And this following chunk of code is the goinout json request:

```
public static String sendGoinoutJsonRequest(String url,String data,long timeout, Hashtable properties, String method) throws IOException {

    HttpConnectionFactory factory = new HttpConnectionFactory(Util.getTransportPriority());
    while(true) {

        HttpConnectionIOSession httpConnectionIOSession = null;
        try {

            HttpConnection httpConnection = factory.getHttpConnection(url);
            if(httpConnection == null) throw new IOException();
            try {

                httpConnection.setRequestMethod(method);
                httpConnection.setRequestProperty("If-Modified-Since","29 Oct 1999 19:43:31 GMT");
                httpConnection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent","Profile/MIDP-2.0 Configuration/CLDC-1.0");
                httpConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                httpConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept","application/json");                    
                httpConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length",data.getBytes().length + "");
                httpConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Language","en-US");
                httpConnection.setRequestProperty("x-rim-transcode-content","none");
                Enumeration keys = properties.keys();
                while(keys.hasMoreElements()) {
                    String key = (String) keys.nextElement();
                    String value = (String) properties.get(key);
                    httpConnection.setRequestProperty(key, value);
                }
                OutputStream outputStream = httpConnection.openOutputStream();
                InputStream inputStream = null;
                if(timeout != -1) {

                    httpConnectionIOSession = new HttpConnectionIOSession(httpConnection,inputStream,outputStream,timeout);

                }
                outputStream.write(data.getBytes());
                outputStream.close();
                int responseCode = httpConnection.getResponseCode();
                if(responseCode != HttpConnection.HTTP_OK) {

                    if(responseCode == HttpConnection.HTTP_BAD_REQUEST) {

                        continue;

                    }
                    if(timeout != -1 && HttpUtils.TIMEOUT + 2000 <= TIMEOUT_MIN) {

                        HttpUtils.TIMEOUT += 2000;

                    }
                    throw new IOException("HTTP " + responseCode + " error code.");

                }
                inputStream = httpConnection.openInputStream();
                final ByteBuffer byteBuffer = new ByteBuffer(inputStream);
                final String response = byteBuffer.getString();
                close(httpConnection,inputStream,outputStream);

                if(timeout != -1 && HttpUtils.TIMEOUT - 1000 >= TIMEOUT_MIN) {

                    HttpUtils.TIMEOUT -= 1000;

                }
                if(httpConnectionIOSession != null) httpConnectionIOSession.interrupt();
                return response;

            } catch(IOException ioException) {

                if(timeout != -1 && HttpUtils.TIMEOUT + 2000 <= TIMEOUT_MIN) {

                    HttpUtils.TIMEOUT += 2000;

                }
                throw ioException;


            }

        } catch(IOException ioException) {

            if(timeout != -1 && HttpUtils.TIMEOUT + 2000 <= TIMEOUT_MIN) {

                HttpUtils.TIMEOUT += 2000;

            }
            throw ioException;

        } finally {
            if(httpConnectionIOSession != null) httpConnectionIOSession.interrupt();
        }

    }

}
```

Look at the properties that I set. If I use this following of properties:

```
httpConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
httpConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept","application/json");
```

what happens is that I could retrieve the JSON data from my BB simulator, and from my real device using wifi connection. BUT, when I use REAL DEVICE using Mobile Service Provider, I will always get IOException: stream closed.

If I use this following code:

```
httpConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/json");
httpConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept","application/json");
```

I always get HTTP Error Code 500 in simulator. And if I use this property in the real device using mobile service provider, the code is keep running because of while(true) there. I wonder if you guys could help me out.

As a matter of fact, This chunk of code is proven work in obtaining json data from Facebook API and Tumblr API. I always use this code and has no problem. I wonder if it could be something wrong with the server side, or I should add another property??? Thank you so much.

Nate request for HttpConnectionFactory:

```
package com.hammyliem.abateify.ui.network;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.Vector;

import javax.microedition.io.Connector;
import javax.microedition.io.HttpConnection;

import net.rim.device.api.io.http.HttpHeaders;
import net.rim.device.api.io.http.HttpProtocolConstants;
import net.rim.device.api.servicebook.ServiceBook;
import net.rim.device.api.servicebook.ServiceRecord;
import net.rim.device.api.system.Branding;
import net.rim.device.api.system.CoverageInfo;
import net.rim.device.api.system.DeviceInfo;
import net.rim.device.api.system.WLANInfo;

public class HttpConnectionFactory {

  public static final int TRANSPORT_WIFI = 1;
  public static final int TRANSPORT_BES = 2;
  public static final int TRANSPORT_BIS = 4;
  public static final int TRANSPORT_DIRECT_TCP = 8;
  public static final int TRANSPORT_WAP2 = 16;
  public static final int TRANSPORT_SIM = 32;

  public static final int TRANSPORTS_ANY = TRANSPORT_WIFI | TRANSPORT_BES | TRANSPORT_BIS | TRANSPORT_DIRECT_TCP | TRANSPORT_WAP2 | TRANSPORT_SIM;
  public static final int TRANSPORTS_AVOID_CARRIER = TRANSPORT_WIFI | TRANSPORT_BES | TRANSPORT_BIS | TRANSPORT_SIM;
  public static final int TRANSPORTS_CARRIER_ONLY = TRANSPORT_DIRECT_TCP | TRANSPORT_WAP2 | TRANSPORT_SIM;

  public static final int DEFAULT_TRANSPORT_ORDER[] = { TRANSPORT_WIFI, TRANSPORT_SIM, TRANSPORT_BIS, TRANSPORT_BES, TRANSPORT_WAP2, TRANSPORT_DIRECT_TCP };

  private static final int TRANSPORT_COUNT = DEFAULT_TRANSPORT_ORDER.length;

  // private static ServiceRecord srMDS[], srBIS[], srWAP2[], srWiFi[];
  private static ServiceRecord srWAP2[];
  private static boolean serviceRecordsLoaded = false;

  private int transports[];
  private int lastTransport = -1;

  public HttpConnectionFactory() {
    this(0);
  }

  public HttpConnectionFactory(int allowedTransports) {
    this(transportMaskToArray(allowedTransports));
  }

  public HttpConnectionFactory(int transportPriority[]) {
    if (!serviceRecordsLoaded) {
      loadServiceBooks(false);
    }
    transports = transportPriority;
  }

  public static String getUserAgent() {
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    sb.append("BlackBerry");
    sb.append(DeviceInfo.getDeviceName());
    sb.append("/");
    sb.append(DeviceInfo.getSoftwareVersion());
    sb.append(" Profile/");
    sb.append(System.getProperty("microedition.profiles"));
    sb.append(" Configuration/");
    sb.append(System.getProperty("microedition.configuration"));
    sb.append(" VendorID/");
    sb.append(Branding.getVendorId());

    return sb.toString();
  }

  public static String getProfile() {
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    sb.append("http://www.blackberry.net/go/mobile/profiles/uaprof/");
    sb.append(DeviceInfo.getDeviceName());
    sb.append("/");
    sb.append(DeviceInfo.getSoftwareVersion().substring(0, 3)); //RDF file format is 4.5.0.rdf (does not include build version)
    sb.append(".rdf");

    return sb.toString();
  }

  public HttpConnection getHttpConnection(String pURL) {
    return getHttpConnection(pURL, null, null);
  }

  public HttpConnection getHttpConnection(String pURL, HttpHeaders headers) {
    return getHttpConnection(pURL, headers, null);
  }

  public HttpConnection getHttpConnection(String pURL, byte[] data) {
    return getHttpConnection(pURL, null, data);
  }

  public HttpConnection getHttpConnection(String pURL, HttpHeaders headers, byte[] data) {

    int curIndex = 0;
    HttpConnection con = null;

    while ((con = tryHttpConnection(pURL, curIndex, headers, data)) == null) {
      try {
        curIndex = nextTransport(curIndex);
      } catch (HttpConnectionFactoryException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        break;
      } finally {
      }
    }

    if (con != null) {
      setLastTransport(transports[curIndex]);
    }

    return con;
  }

  private int nextTransport(int curIndex) throws HttpConnectionFactoryException {
    if ((curIndex >= 0) && (curIndex < transports.length - 1)) {
      return curIndex + 1;
    } else {
      throw new HttpConnectionFactoryException("No more transport available.");
    }
  }

  private HttpConnection tryHttpConnection(String pURL, int tIndex, HttpHeaders headers, byte[] data) {

    HttpConnection con = null;
    OutputStream os = null;

    switch (transports[tIndex]) {
    case TRANSPORT_SIM:
      try {
        con = getSimConnection(pURL, false);
      } catch (IOException e) {
      } finally {
        break;
      }
    case TRANSPORT_WIFI:
      try {
        con = getWifiConnection(pURL);
      } catch (IOException e) {
      } finally {
        break;
      }
    case TRANSPORT_BES:
      try {
        con = getBesConnection(pURL);
      } catch (IOException e) {
      } finally {
        break;
      }
    case TRANSPORT_BIS:
      try {
        con = getBisConnection(pURL);
      } catch (IOException e) {
      } finally {
        break;
      }
    case TRANSPORT_DIRECT_TCP:
      try {
        con = getTcpConnection(pURL);
      } catch (IOException e) {
      } finally {
        break;
      }
    case TRANSPORT_WAP2:
      try {
        con = getWap2Connection(pURL);
      } catch (IOException e) {
      } finally {
        break;
      }
    }

    if (con != null) {
      try {
        //add headers to connection
        if (headers != null) {
          int size = headers.size();

          for (int i = 0; i < size;) {
            String header = headers.getPropertyKey(i);
            String value = headers.getPropertyValue(i++);

            if (value != null) {
              con.setRequestProperty(header, value);

            }
          }
        }
        // post data
        if (data != null) {
          con.setRequestMethod(HttpConnection.POST);
          con.setRequestProperty(HttpProtocolConstants.HEADER_CONTENT_TYPE, HttpProtocolConstants.CONTENT_TYPE_APPLICATION_X_WWW_FORM_URLENCODED);
          con.setRequestProperty(HttpProtocolConstants.HEADER_CONTENT_LENGTH, String.valueOf(data.length));

          os = con.openOutputStream();
          os.write(data);
        } else {
          con.setRequestMethod(HttpConnection.GET);
        }

      } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }

    return con;
  }

  public int getLastTransport() {
    return lastTransport;
  }

  public String getLastTransportName() {
    return getTransportName(getLastTransport());
  }

  private void setLastTransport(int pLastTransport) {
    lastTransport = pLastTransport;
  }

  private HttpConnection getSimConnection(String pURL, boolean mdsSimulatorRunning) throws IOException {
    if (DeviceInfo.isSimulator()) {
      if (mdsSimulatorRunning) {
        return getConnection(pURL, ";deviceside=false", null);
      } else {
        return getConnection(pURL, ";deviceside=true", null);
      }
    }
    return null;
  }

  private HttpConnection getBisConnection(String pURL) throws IOException {
    if (CoverageInfo.isCoverageSufficient(4 /* CoverageInfo.COVERAGE_BIS_B */)) {
      return getConnection(pURL, ";deviceside=false;ConnectionType=mds-public", null);
    }
    return null;
  }

  private HttpConnection getBesConnection(String pURL) throws IOException {
    if (CoverageInfo.isCoverageSufficient(2 /* CoverageInfo.COVERAGE_MDS */)) {
      return getConnection(pURL, ";deviceside=false", null);
    }
    return null;
  }

  private HttpConnection getWifiConnection(String pURL) throws IOException {
    if (WLANInfo.getWLANState() == WLANInfo.WLAN_STATE_CONNECTED) {
      return getConnection(pURL, ";interface=wifi", null);
    }
    return null;
  }

  private HttpConnection getWap2Connection(String pURL) throws IOException {
    if (CoverageInfo.isCoverageSufficient(1 /* CoverageInfo.COVERAGE_DIRECT */) && (srWAP2 != null) && (srWAP2.length != 0)) {
      return getConnection(pURL, ";deviceside=true;ConnectionUID=", srWAP2[0].getUid());
    }
    return null;
  }

  private HttpConnection getTcpConnection(String pURL) throws IOException {
    if (CoverageInfo.isCoverageSufficient(1 /* CoverageInfo.COVERAGE_DIRECT */)) {
      return getConnection(pURL, ";deviceside=true", null);
    }
    return null;
  }

  private HttpConnection getConnection(String pURL, String transportExtras1, String transportExtras2) throws IOException {
    StringBuffer fullUrl = new StringBuffer();
    fullUrl.append(pURL);
    if (transportExtras1 != null) {
      fullUrl.append(transportExtras1);
    }
    if (transportExtras2 != null) {
      fullUrl.append(transportExtras2);
    }
    return (HttpConnection) Connector.open(fullUrl.toString());
  }

  public static void reloadServiceBooks() {
    loadServiceBooks(true);
  }

  private static synchronized void loadServiceBooks(boolean reload) {
    if (serviceRecordsLoaded && !reload) {
      return;
    }
    ServiceBook sb = ServiceBook.getSB();
    ServiceRecord[] records = sb.getRecords();
    Vector mdsVec = new Vector();
    Vector bisVec = new Vector();
    Vector wap2Vec = new Vector();
    Vector wifiVec = new Vector();

    if (!serviceRecordsLoaded) {
      for (int i = 0; i < records.length; i++) {
        ServiceRecord myRecord = records[i];
        String cid, uid;

        if (myRecord.isValid() && !myRecord.isDisabled()) {
          cid = myRecord.getCid().toLowerCase();
          uid = myRecord.getUid().toLowerCase();
          if ((cid.indexOf("wptcp") != -1) && (uid.indexOf("wap2") != -1) && (uid.indexOf("wifi") == -1) && (uid.indexOf("mms") == -1)) {
            wap2Vec.addElement(myRecord);
          }
        }
      }

      srWAP2 = new ServiceRecord[wap2Vec.size()];
      wap2Vec.copyInto(srWAP2);
      wap2Vec.removeAllElements();
      wap2Vec = null;

      serviceRecordsLoaded = true;
    }
  }

  public static int[] transportMaskToArray(int mask) {
    if (mask == 0) {
      mask = TRANSPORTS_ANY;
    }
    int numTransports = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < TRANSPORT_COUNT; i++) {
      if ((DEFAULT_TRANSPORT_ORDER[i] & mask) != 0) {
        numTransports++;
      }
    }
    int transports[] = new int[numTransports];
    int index = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < TRANSPORT_COUNT; i++) {
      if ((DEFAULT_TRANSPORT_ORDER[i] & mask) != 0) {
        transports[index++] = DEFAULT_TRANSPORT_ORDER[i];
      }
    }
    return transports;
  }

  private static String getTransportName(int transport) {
    String tName;
    switch (transport) {
    case TRANSPORT_WIFI:
      tName = "WIFI";
      break;
    case TRANSPORT_BES:
      tName = "BES";
      break;
    case TRANSPORT_BIS:
      tName = "BIS";
      break;
    case TRANSPORT_DIRECT_TCP:
      tName = "TCP";
      break;
    case TRANSPORT_WAP2:
      tName = "WAP2";
      break;
    case TRANSPORT_SIM:
      tName = "SIM";
      break;
    default:
      tName = "UNKNOWN";
      break;
    }
    return tName;
  }

}
```

Comment: If the code works via Wi-Fi and **not** over the carrier network, you also might need to show us what your `HttpConnectionFactory` class does.  It might be creating the correct kind of connection for Wi-Fi, but not for other transports.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I'm a little unclear why this question is tagged `android`.  Perhaps it's too late, and I'm missing something.  Anyway, I'm answering this as a **BlackBerry** question.

First of all, if you're encoding a set of parameters with normal URL encoding for your **request**, and expecting JSON in the **response**, then your original code:

```java
httpConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
httpConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept","application/json");
```

is correct.  Don't set `Content-Type` to `application/json` if your request's content is URL-encoded parameters.

Second, I'm not 100% sure, but I believe you are performing this network request on the UI thread.  Even though I can't see the code that calls `loginGoinoutWithFacebook()`, I believe you're doing it on the UI thread, because that method contains a call to `Dialog.alert()`, which is a UI method.

**Don't make network calls on the UI thread!**

Probably what's happening (assuming you set the content type to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`) is that over Wi-Fi, the network request completes really quickly, and the UI isn't blocked too long.  It *appears* to work.

However, when you're on the Mobile Carrier Network, everything is slower.  You block the UI thread for too long, and that causes problems.  I can't remember exactly what the symptoms of making network calls on the UI thread are (because I never do it), but I would bet that this is your problem.

Use a background `Thread` / `Runnable` to perform your network calls:

```java
Thread worker = new Thread(new Runnable() {
   // this method is run on a background thread:
   public void run() {
      final JSONObject response = loginGoinoutWithFacebook(token);

      // to update the UI with the response, we must use the UI thread:
      UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable() {
          public void run() {
              // this just shows an alert, but you can insert your
              //  own code to update the UI properly with the response
              //  contents
              Dialog.alert(response.toString());
          }
      });
   }
});

worker.start();
```

Comment: So are you saying that, the stream is closed because I do not use thread to do a network call?

Comment: I have done as what you said.. Making call with a thread. It still gives me stream closed error. and it throws IO Exception...

Comment: You **definitely** should be using a thread for the network call, but if you've changed that, and still have problems, then there must be *another* problem.  Does it still work over Wi-Fi?

Comment: It does work over wifi... and after I talk with the server guy, he said the request is never reached to the server... that is why I never get anything. in addition, I get stream closed. I wonder if this could be a mobile carrier problem. but then my mobile can access internet and login to facebook. really confusing.

Comment: So, the value of `Content-Type` won't make a difference if the problem is that you're never reaching the server.  BlackBerry works very differently over different *transports*, so having something work on Wi-Fi but not over the carrier network isn't that unusual.  I would look at your `HttpConnectionFactory` class closely.  If you only need to support OS 5.0+ users, you might consider rewriting that class to use the BlackBerry `ConnectionFactory` class.  You may still want to wrap it with your own code to customize the user agent string, but the basics of creating connections can be inherited.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect there are two different problems here in addition to the possibility that you are running your code on the Event Thread as pointed out by Nate.

I am not sure that your are running on the Event Thread because your application will be terminated with a Application Not Responding exception if you were.  But as Nate points out, you will get an Exception if you try to execute a Dialog off the Event Thread.  So I would expect an Exception either way....

To summarise the reported problems, it seems that you get one of the following:
a) an IOException on the connection when running using the Wireless data service on device (as opposed to WiFi)
b) an HTTP code 500 when sending the data with a specific header.  This means a Server has returned your request telling you that it has not understood it. So you are sending something incorrectly.

First I suggest you investigate the IOException - basically print out the detail of the exception that you get (toString() will do it).  This will give you more detail on the problem.  There are a number of choices, I'm guessing it will be a time out, but would like to know before I attempt to suggest a solution.

Can I refer to back to your previous Thread : [blackberry-get-error-code-411](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19653402/blackberry-get-error-code-411)  Please read my response again.

There were two points in there that are critical to all communications, not just the 411 error:

1. The encoding used for the data transmitted
2. The connection method used.

The encoding is perhaps key here for the 500 return code.  When you tell the server you are sending JSON data it probably expects that the data will be UTF-8 encoded.  However the data you send does not appear to be.  If you are using just the standard Latin-1 characters then this will not be a problem.  If your JSON data contains characters not included in that character set, then the data will not be encoded correctly and this may be why your Server does not understand it.

So for safety, when sending JSON data, I suggest you UTF-8 encode it (and remember that the number of bytes generated is NOT necessarily the same as the number of characters in the String).

Further with respect to the 500 error code (in fact any error code), I recommend that you dump out the headers on the response you receive back.  They will probably identify the Server that actually returned the request.  It may not be your Server - when processing over a mobile network as there are other gateways involved that can reject requests.

In summary, to investigate this problem (or any other network problem) I suggest you:

1. Print out the detail from any Exceptions you get
2. Make sure you know what connection method is used for the failing
   request
3. If you do not get a good return code, dump out the headers so you
   find out which Server actually gave you the return code
4. Make sure you correctly encode (character encode to bytes) the
   data you are sending (and correct decode bytes you are received if
   you convert these back to characters).

One final thing.  Since the Server is giving you a 500 - I suggest you log the post data before you send it, on a failure, you can check that it is properly formatted.

Comment: I'm sure *your* code never does this, but running a slow network operation on the main/UI thread is not actually guaranteed to throw any exceptions.  You can do it.  It's just a really bad idea.  The OP states that his code works over Wi-Fi, but doesn't on the carrier network.  There certainly could be other problems, but my guess was that the call completes over Wi-Fi quickly, and slowly over the carrier network.  In any case, he likely has multiple problems, and I think understanding the `Content-Type` parameter, and getting the network call off the UI thread would help narrow it down.

Comment: HttpConnectionFactory is also provided there.

Comment: I asked the server guy in the company, he said that I should use application/json for content type and accept. Furthermore, I have tried using UTF-8.. still can't have any luck. I said to them that I use the same code to retrieve data from Facebook json response and I have no problems. So could it be the server settings that are not universal enough?

Comment: @HammyLin, I think the company guy is wrong.  `Content-Type` describes your **request**.  `Accept` describes the responses.  That's why they have two different properties.  If the server API really does want the **request** as JSON, then you'll have to format it as JSON, which your code doesn't do (`httpConnection.setRequestProperty(key, value);`).  The way your Java code is, you should either be setting your `Content-Type` to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, or else you need to encode the request payload as JSON.  That you get server code 500 when using JSON tells me that's the wrong one.